# i want find a whole contour in image

Tags: opencv, contour

I want to find a complete contour in the picture as shown in red rectangle，  but find multiple contours as shown in green rectangle

Below is the code

```
 def getContours(self, img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 5, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0:CONTOURS_CNT]
    return contours
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZNle.png)

Comment: you probably want to detect **text**, not arbitrary contours. try this: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d43/tutorial_dnn_text_spotting.html

Comment: Please clarify your question more specifically